# How can I prohibit users who can only "see all contacts" (but have no edit rights) to send emails, print labels, etc (actions)?

Tags: email, permissions

Users who have the rights to SEE all contacts (but no edit rights) can also interact with them (sending emails, etc.). How is it possible to prohibit those users to send emails, print labels, etc. to the contacts, as they have "view only" rights?
Thx in advance for your help!

Comment: Assuming there isn't a simple permission that has been overlooked I would usually start by asking why the folk who need to SEE all contacts actually need access to civicrm itself, eg could they get what they need via an access controlled Drupal View (or WP equivalent) or even via a civicrm profile listing. So it may help folk answer if you can clarify more about what these users really need to 'see'.

Comment: mentioning your CMS may help

Comment: I use Drupal. I am not a specialist... I see in the permissions that people who can see the contact fields have also the right to interact with them (with the action menu). I would like to let them see all the common and the personnalized fields without been able to send emails, etc.

Comment: as per my earlier comment, if you want to avoid doing custom development then using Drupal Views may be the easier soluion. keep those users out of civicrm all together and just build drupal views to show the information they need